# How to get the current database in the django migration?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, database-migration

I am writing a very custom migration in django, and I would like to make it work with the

```
django-admin migrate --database databse_name
```

command. Since I am creating a custom cursor, the default won't work for me. Is there any reasonable way to make it work?

Comment: Do you need to run migration on specified database?

Comment: If I just want to do that once, I can just change the default in the config. But I would like my migration to work with that for the long term. As is, I think  I need to make it crash by default, to prevent someone migrating the wrong database accidentally.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14442569/5098707) may help you.

Comment: @ErnestTen No, not at all. I am just trying to get the name of the database that was passed to migrate. It is already in my database_config.py, I just need my script to know which one.

Comment: You can always extend the [`migrate`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py) and add your custom logic to it..

Comment: @karthikr Sure, but I was hoping there was a not-terrible way to do this. If I am to modify django, I can get by with just having to make this migration more manually each time. My use case is just not big enough.

Comment: Are you looking for the `allow_migrate` method in the database router? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate

Comment: Or possibly, providing hints to the database router: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/writing-migrations/

Comment: @Wolph This could possibly used to achieve what I want, but no. 
All I want is to make my custom cursor connect to the right databas when migrate is run with `--database `

Answer (score 4):

It's "let's answer really old questions" time!

Below info taken from the current-as-of-now [django 3.0 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#runpython)

Your migration function will take a second argument which is a `SchemaEditor` object.  This gives you the database for your commands.

```py
def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    # We get the model from the versioned app registry;
    # if we directly import it, it'll be the wrong version
    Country = apps.get_model("myapp", "Country")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    Country.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        Country(name="USA", code="us"),
        Country(name="France", code="fr"),
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been waiting all those years! In all seriousness, this does seem like the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can access it by using `db.db_alias`. Hope it helps!