# Dynamic database connection in Django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlalchemy

I'm just prototyping an idea of mine for which I must be able to connect to multiple databases (of multiple types) using **Django**. I'm aware that it's possible to define several db in settings.py and that we can specify which database a manager should use by using `using('db_name')`, but unfortunately I can't hard-code my multiple databases in the settings file, since they are dynamic (I mean I don't know at "compile time" which and how many external database I will use). The problem is similar to this one, already asked and answered here: [Django: dynamic database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254315/django-dynamic-database-file)

...but, the accepted answer is IMO just an hack, and I have several concerns about the reliability and security of a similar approach.
So my question is: is there a clean and safe way to establish a database connection dynamically via a somewhat lower level API (like in **SQLAlchemy**'s `create_engine('db_url')`)? If not is it possible to integrate **SQLAlchemy** in **Django** (in a reliable and fully working way)?

ps. another thing I would like to avoid is to have to specify for each ORM action which db to use with `using()`, instead I like the idea of `SQLAlchemy`'s `transaction` or alternatively a context processor for which I can write something like:

```
with active_db('some_db') as db:
    # do ORM operations...
```

Comment: what database do you use? mysql? postgre?

Comment: as I wrote I don't use a single type of db, I could have N remote postgres dbs + N remote oracle dbs + N mysql dbs or none of them