# Django : Dynamically create a database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I Would like to implement a web page in Django which allow a user to dynamically create a Data Base.

The Django model stored will always be the same. (a generic user)

Scenario :

1. The user fills up a form with fields like user.firstname, user.lastname ..
2. Then after the submit, django creates a brand new DB on the DBMS.
3. The model is then stored in this new DB.
4. Django save/store this DB setting for further use.

I find out [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/) that it's possible to set up multiple DB's in Django but that implies that they already have been created (Which is obviously not my case).

To create my DB I can think of executing an custom SQL query directly  on the DBMS like that

```
from django.db import connection

def createNewDB(self,id):
    with connection.cursort() as cursor:
        queryStr = "\"CREATE DATABASE " + id + "\"" 
        cursor.execute(queryStr)
```

But then I have no clues about :

- How to save the new DB settings in Django DB (see below).
- How to migrate and save the model user in the DB

  - Migrate :
    `from django.core.management import call_command
    call_command("migrate", interactive=False)`
  - Save model : `user.save(using='db_id')`

I find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254315/django-dynamic-database-file?answertab=votes#tab-top) talking about how to add a connection dynamically with :

```
from django.db import connections
connections.databases['new-alias'] = { ... }
conn = connections['new-alias']
```

But again in, this case the sqlite DB exist before, so I'm not sure if it is what I need.

So is it possible to create a DB link to a model and then add it to django's database setting ?

Or should I review all my data structure ? (like one DB but multiple user model table)

I am using django 2.0.5 and postgreSQL 9.6 but I can change if the solution is not compatible (sqlite for example).

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/OmniDB/OmniDB - could be the thing for you.

Comment: @wiesion Thanks,so you mean that I should take a look to the source code of OmniDB ?

Comment: I think you could clone the repo and set up the required environment. Based on that, continue to create your own apps in the project.