# Django model with dynamic db tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-database, django-datatable

I am using Django to interface with another (JAVA) application that based on some events generates at runtime tables in the db with the same model. So I don't have a direct control over the DB. For example:

```
Sensor1
id | value | time
1      10      2018-10-11

Sensor2
id | value | time
1      12     2018-10-11
```

Currently, my Django model is looking something like this:

```
class Sensor(models.Model):
 value = models.IntegerField()
 time = models.DatetimeField()

 class Meta:
  managed = False
  db_table = "Sensor1"
```

Do you have any clue if I can set the model somehow to be able to gain the data from a different table based on the query?
Ideally, something that would allow me to get the data in the fashion of:

```
config_tables=['Sensor1','Sensor2']

for table in config_tables:
 data = Sensor.objects.table(table).objects.all()
 ...
```

Other possibility might be also to have a SQL query that executes on different tables, so perhaps something like:

```
SELECT * FROM %s;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: dynamic database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254315/django-dynamic-database-file)

Comment: @Selcuk the proposed solution is for another databse, not for another table. The solution proposed there does not solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the best solution so far is to make a custom SQL Query so in this example it could be something like this in models.py:

```
def get_all_parameters(db_table):
    return Parameters.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM %s' % db_table)
```

and call it as:

```
get_all_parameters('Sensor1')
```

or as:

```
TABLES = ['Sensor1', 'Sensor2']

for table in TABLES:
 parameters = get_all_parameters(table) 
 ...
```