# Django when i create one user, one database created

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I often look for answers on this website,this time my question was not answered.
I have a question:
    **when i create one user in web Interface,i want to create a database at this point. the database name according to username.in other words,I want to have a separate database for each user**,My database is **mysql**.
    I'm looking for one demo.thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django multiple and dynamic databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585373/django-multiple-and-dynamic-databases)

Comment: @Zev I tried configuration, but I failed,I don't really understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot post comments yet, here is another way you could handle what you are trying to accomplish. It might give you some ideas on how you want to design your application as well. There are different ways to handle users with their own "database". I have personally used this framework in a production app on heroku and I recommend it.

[Django Tenants](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm sorry that my database is **mysql**, which seems to be unsupported.