# Connect to databases dynamically in Django

Tags: django, api

I'm new to Django.

My project database architecture is like

Having 'Auth_DB' contains all the users login details.

Once user logged in, then in need to fetch the details from the other DB. Here i have databases for each user individually, like:

```
user_0001
user_0002
user_0003
user_0004
user_0005
```

Can any one please help how can i achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A database per user? Really? How are your models defined? I am wondering if you do not make a confusion.

Comment: One question, does this mean that with each new user, you create a new database dynamically and migrate a predefined schema to this database?

Comment: @Kanak same model can be used, as the tables, columns would be same.

Comment: @AhmedHosny yes. Currently my system contains few set of databases. I would like to provide API's.

Comment: @MadhuP Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/11292526/7890592

Comment: @MuthurajS Thanks. I Have gone through the solution earlier, but haven't tried. Now i tried and get implemented it works.

Comment: @MuthurajS can we follow the same procedure for setting throttling limit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django multiple and dynamic databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585373/django-multiple-and-dynamic-databases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed [Django multiple and dynamic databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585373/django-multiple-and-dynamic-databases/11292526#11292526)

In summary, this is the process:

1. Add the new database to settings (at runtime)
2. Create a file to store these settings for reloading when the server is restarted (at runtime)
3. Run a script which loads the saved settings files (whenever the server is restarted)