# how to connect database programatically at runtime in #django framework

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have in my User Profile, one field to define the Database name, that user can connect.

```
DATABASES = {
    'app_data': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
    },
    'DBNAME_1': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    }
}

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    dbname = models.CharField(u'Database name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

not connecting to 2 different database only creating in single database

Comment: Why do you expect this to use two different databases?

Comment: want to change so

Answer (score 0):

You can use database of your choice with using keyword at runtime.

```
UserProfile.objects.using('user_data').all()
```

Comment: You can create a seperate database connection and write raw sql queries.

Comment: how to create seperate database connection??

Comment: if you are using postgres then                                                                     `conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host, database=database, user=user, password=password)
        cur = conn.cursor()`                                                                                     then write query as                                                                                     `sql = "select * from any_table;" `                                           `cursor.execute(sql)` then `data = cursor.fetchall()`

Comment: I want to create a database dynamically at runtime in mysql or sqlite. And not by using raw sql queries. Pls suggest me?

Comment: This answers you in better way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585373/django-multiple-and-dynamic-databases