# how to dynamicly change db password in django settings

Tags: django, database, django-settings

I have a case when my db requires new token generated dynamicly as a password every 15 minutes. But it is advice from django team not to modify settings at runtime. And I found out that this is really not so easy to accomplish. I already tried this approche:

[Django multiple and dynamic databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585373/django-multiple-and-dynamic-databases)

but it seems more complex then it could be ...

Comment: which DB is this?

Comment: This is postgis